# Nested variable in Ansible referencing a list

Tags: variables, ansible, jinja2

I'm hoping to get some guidance on the following code which involves a nested variable in Ansible. Here's the playbook:

```
---
- name: Testing
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    hostname: HOST1
    VLAN_DEFS: [
        {
            "TAG": "1001",
            "HOST1_DATA_IP": "10.10.0.1",
            "HOST2_DATA_IP": "10.20.0.1",
            "DATA_NETMASK": "24"
        },
        {
            "TAG": "1002",
            "HOST1_DATA_IP": "10.10.0.2",
            "HOST2_DATA_IP": "10.20.0.2",
            "DATA_NETMASK": "24"
        },
        {
            "TAG": "1003",
            "HOST1_DATA_IP": "10.10.0.3",
            "HOST2_DATA_IP": "10.20.0.3",
            "DATA_NETMASK": "24"
        }
    ]

  tasks:

    - template:
        src: ./test.j2
        dest: ./output.json
```

And here is the test.j2 Jinja template:

```
[
{% for VLAN in VLAN_DEFS %}

    {
        "VLAN": "VLAN{{ VLAN.TAG }}",
        "ADDRESS": "{{ lookup('vars', 'VLAN.' ~ hostname ~ '_DATA_IP') }}/{{ VLAN.DATA_NETMASK }}"
    }{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}

]
```

The lookup line I'm using appears to give me what I want which is VLAN.HOST1_DATA_IP, but it's not being interpreted as a valid variable. The result of my playbook is the error "No variable found with this name: VLAN.HOST1_DATA_IP."  However, if I replace the ADDRESS line with that exact value as illustrated below, it works fine:

```
"ADDRESS": "{{ VLAN.HOST1_DATA_IP }}/{{ VLAN.DATA_NETMASK }}"
```

Does anyone by chance have some insight into why this error is occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use a `vars` lookup. Instead of `var.attribute`, use `var[attribute]`, which allows to build the attribute name with an expression, like this:

```
[
{% for VLAN in VLAN_DEFS %}
    {
        "VLAN": "VLAN{{ VLAN.TAG }}",
        "ADDRESS": "{{ VLAN[hostname ~ '_DATA_IP'] }}/{{ VLAN.DATA_NETMASK }}"
    }{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}

]
```

Which produces:

```
[
    {
        "VLAN": "VLAN1001",
        "ADDRESS": "10.10.0.1/24"
    },    {
        "VLAN": "VLAN1002",
        "ADDRESS": "10.10.0.2/24"
    },    {
        "VLAN": "VLAN1003",
        "ADDRESS": "10.10.0.3/24"
    }
]
```

Comment: Good call.  Worked perfectly.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make the code robust using the filters *from_yaml* and *to_json*. At the same time simplify the code by putting the conversion into the *vars*

```yaml
  vlan_list: |
    {% filter from_yaml %}
    {% for VLAN in VLAN_DEFS %}
    - ADDRESS: {{ VLAN[hostname ~ '_DATA_IP'] }}/{{ VLAN.DATA_NETMASK }}
      VLAN: VLAN{{ VLAN.TAG }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfilter %}
```

gives the YAML list

```yaml
  vlan_list:
  - ADDRESS: 10.10.0.1/24
    VLAN: VLAN1001
  - ADDRESS: 10.10.0.2/24
    VLAN: VLAN1002
  - ADDRESS: 10.10.0.3/24
    VLAN: VLAN1003
```

Now, the template is trivial

```yaml
shell> cat test.j2
{{ vlan_list|to_nice_json }}
```

The filters take care of YAML/JSON syntax and formatting.

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    hostname: HOST1
    VLAN_DEFS:
      - DATA_NETMASK: '24'
        HOST1_DATA_IP: 10.10.0.1
        HOST2_DATA_IP: 10.20.0.1
        TAG: '1001'
      - DATA_NETMASK: '24'
        HOST1_DATA_IP: 10.10.0.2
        HOST2_DATA_IP: 10.20.0.2
        TAG: '1002'
      - DATA_NETMASK: '24'
        HOST1_DATA_IP: 10.10.0.3
        HOST2_DATA_IP: 10.20.0.3
        TAG: '1003'

    vlan_list: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for VLAN in VLAN_DEFS %}
      - ADDRESS: {{ VLAN[hostname ~ '_DATA_IP'] }}/{{ VLAN.DATA_NETMASK }}
        VLAN: VLAN{{ VLAN.TAG }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: vlan_list

    - template:
        src: test.j2
        dest: /tmp/test.json
```

Creates the JSON file

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/test.json 
[
    {
        "ADDRESS": "10.10.0.1/24",
        "VLAN": "VLAN1001"
    },
    {
        "ADDRESS": "10.10.0.2/24",
        "VLAN": "VLAN1002"
    },
    {
        "ADDRESS": "10.10.0.3/24",
        "VLAN": "VLAN1003"
    }
]
```